# Using Unison repeat = watch on CentOS7 "Fatal error: No file monitoring helper program found."

Tags: centos7, unison

So after installing Unison on CentOS 7, i wanted to use the repeat=watch function. syncing by running unison manually works perfect. But for a auto-sync on change, `repeat=watch` could be  used. But this line gives me the error:

`Fatal error: No file monitoring helper program found.`

This probably means that it can't find the fsmonitor.py (at least, that is what I think).

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue this way:

1: install ocaml and ctags
`yum install ocaml ocaml-camlp4-devel ctags ctags-etags`

2: install inotify:

3: install python-inotify

wget rpm:

`rpm -Uvh RPM FILE NAME*rpm`

1. Install python-inotify rpm package:
   `yum install python-inotify`

download svn dump van unison

```
svn checkout https://webdav.seas.upenn.edu/svn/unison
cd trunk
make NATIVE=true UISTYLE=text
sudo cp src/unison /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp src/fsmonitor.py /usr/local/bin/
```

creating a private-public key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
ssh-copy-id root@IP
```

unison config in root/.unison

```
root=var/www

root=ssh://IPaddr//var/www/

batch=true

repeat=watch

prefer=newer
```

i do not know if any step i took was irrelevant, but it worked at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First I installed pyinotify but it isn't helped. After that I've removed everything from folder on server from

```
cd $HOME/.unison
rm -rf *
```

and it's helped me.

I've made this problem because version of Unison on host and server were different.